# Openserver как правильно использовать SSL

Tags: ssl, https, openserver

В документации на Openserver написано что SSL включен автоматически. Добавил сертификат от Openserver в корневые, но при загрузке сайта Chrome и FireFox ругаются что сертификат выдан на другой URL и не пускают на сайт. Как правильно настроить работу с https под Openserver? Нужно отключить эти проверки в браузерах? Создать для каждого сайта свой сертификат, добавить его в корневые? Или есть какое то более красивое решение что бы браузеры не ругались при использовании сертификата Openserver на локальных сайтах?

Comment: Доступ к https-сайтам осуществляется по порту (смотри настройки openserver, стандартно там прописано - 444), т.е. путь к сайту: https://твой-сайт:444

Comment: Нужно получить сертификат на нужный адрес. Если вы это делаете в целях отладки, то можно использовать самозаверенный или произвольный сертификат и обходить это уже в браузере.

Comment: Разве не 443 порт по умолчанию для https?